# Microsoftgraph Excel calculation without modifying file

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I have an Excel file that calculates a product advise based on several input variables. To use this in a web application and let users define the input variables I want to use the Microsoft graph Excel API, but can't figure out if it's possible to make the calculations without actually copying & modifying the original Excel file.

Currently I got a workaround solution that requires three API calls to do this:

- One to copy the original file (`POST .../drive/root:/filename.xlsx:/copy {name:'newfilename.xlsx'}`)
- One to update one or more cell values (`PATCH .../drive/root:/newfilename.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets('worksheetname')/range('address=A1') {values:'...'}`)
- One to get the calculated values (`GET .../drive/root:/newfilename.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets('worksheetname')/range('address=A2')`)

Obviously this is not the desired solution, but I cannot find any easier solution in the documentation.
Is there anyway to improve this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your calculation depends only on the existing state (pre-defined templates, formulas) of the workbook, you can just have 1 copy of the file in the drive and re-use for many calculations without saving the document. Essentially, you can use Excel file as a calc-engine and use the resulting values from updates.

For this, you'd need to create a session that doesn't save updates before making any API call to modify data.

`POST /{version}/me/drive/items/01CYZLFJGUJ7JHBSZDFZFL25KSZGQTVAUN/workbook/createSession`

Body:

`{ "persistChanges": false }`

Response:

`{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/$metadata#microsoft.graph.sessionInfo",
  "id": "{session-id}",
  "persistChanges": false
}`

The resulting session header should be attached in the following HTTP calls. As long as you do that, it doesn't save your changes.

on next calls, add HTTP header:

`workbook-session-id: {session-id}`

Note: you may run into session limitation on a given file. If you expect a lot of concurrent requests then you should make copies of the Excel file to distribute the load.

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked this part in the documentation (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/excel).